# A property of model becomes null while posting

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new to MVC. Now I'm trying with a simple demo of MVC that to print Customer's information to screen and update it, send back to database.

I have no idea why the Customer's ID becomes null while the others are fine.

I want to display Customer's ID to the screen but I don't want user to edit it to post to my database. I've been researching this for some hours now..

my code :

**Customer.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace PeopleManagement.Models
{
    public class Customer
    {
        [Required]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int Age { get; set; }

        public Customer()
        {

        }
        public Customer(string id, string name, int age)
        {
            Id = id;
            this.Name = name;
            this.Age = age;
        }
    }
}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@using System.Web.UI.WebControls
@using PeopleManagement.Models
@model IList<Customer>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>First MVC Application</title>
        <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/css/customized-table.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>

    <body style="max-width:100%; max-height:100%">

        <div id="pageTitle" style="text-align:center; color:red; font-size:24px; font-weight:bold;">Customer Management</div>
        @using (@Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            <div id="tablePanel" style="padding-top: 15px">

                <table class="customized_table" border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Age</th>
                    </tr>

                    @{
                        for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model[i].Name);
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model[i].Name, new {@style = "min-width:100%; text-align:center", @disable = "true"})
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model[i].Age)
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    }
                </table>

            </div>

            <div>
                <p><input type="submit"/></p>
            </div>

        }

    </body>

</html>

<script>

</script>
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using PeopleManagement.Models;

namespace PeopleManagement.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public List<Customer> CustomersList { get; private set; } = new List<Customer>(5);

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            CustomersList.Add(new Customer("ID_1", "Name_1", 1));
            CustomersList.Add(new Customer("ID_2", "Name_2", 2));
            CustomersList.Add(new Customer("ID_3", "Name_3", 3));

            ModelState.Clear();
            return View(CustomersList);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(List<Customer> postbackCustomers)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return View(CustomersList);

            CustomersList = postbackCustomers;

            return View(CustomersList);
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Apart from not including a hidden input as indicated in the answers below (1) You should not have both a hidden input and textbox for property `Name`. I assume you trying to disable the textbox which `@disable = "true"` will not do (its `disabled="disabled"`), but just make it `readonly="readonly"` and delete the hidden input. (2) `ModelState.Clear();` is pointless  - nothing has been added to `ModelState` in your GET method. (3) `return View(CustomersList);` makes no sense - why would you return an empty list if the model was not valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MVC if you want to get some value back from view you have to have that value in the view first. It seems you have not inputted the Id in the view.

Change your view code like this,

```
for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model[i].Id)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model[i].Name, new { @style = "min-width:100%; text-align:center", @disable = "true" })
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model[i].Age)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
```

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are not showing the ID on the index.html view, The customer ID has value in your example. You should try to show it in read only mode in the for each loop.

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model[i].Id)
```

Comment: How can I protect m ID when I used @Html.DisplayFor ? Because now, I can change the submit data by using browser's debugger. ?